# process list items in different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

At the moment I have List of Job objects that are queued to be processed sequentially shown in the code bellow.

```
   List<Job> jobList = jobQueue.GetJobsWithStatus(Status.New);
   foreach (Job job in jobList)
   {               
        job.Process();
   }
```

I am interested in running several Jobs at the same time in a limited number of threads (lets say 5 threads).

What is the best way to do this in c#?

**Additional Notes:**

- A Job object does not share resources
  with other jobs.
- Each Job takes about    10 seconds to
  process.
- Each job could    connect to
  different resources.

**Update:** I have used a Semaphore because I could not limit the amount of active threads with a ThreadPool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're feeling adventurous you can use C# 4.0 and the Task Parallel Library:

```
Parallel.ForEach(jobList, curJob => {
  curJob.Process()
});
```

Comment: Very interesting Sid, At the moment I am using Visual Studio 2008 with .NET 3.5. Sadly, I don't think I will be able to use 4.0 on the live servers until it becomes Gold.

Comment: Understandable, I'm still stuck using .NET 2.0 :(

Answer (score 3):

You will want to look into thread pools (for the simple answer).  There is even a ThreadPool class in C# and it is quite easy to set up with great examples in the [msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()

This will queue a method for execution.  It will execute when a thread pool thread is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to use Threading, simple coding:

```
private static void TransferThread(ThreadStart tstart)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(tstart);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
}
```

Or you can you [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx). This allows you to use any available thread and return it back to the pool after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the .NET ThreadPool a try.